# Heroku edit ssh_config under etc/ssh/ssh_config

Tags: heroku, ssh, ssh-config

I need to add "dynamically" ssh keys in the file ssh_config, but i can't edit it because it's read only. Did you already add somes keys in an heroku instance ?

Flow -> User signup -> New Key is generated and the public_key is sent to the User and the server edit the ssh_config file.